# how to convert xlsx to tab delimited files

Tags: python, excel, macos, csv

I have quite a lot of xlsx files which is a pain to convert them one by one to tab delimited files

I would like to know if there is any solution to do this by python. Here what I found and what tried to do with failure 
This I found and I tried the solution but did not work [Mass Convert .xls and .xlsx to .txt (Tab Delimited) on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798864/mass-convert-xls-and-xlsx-to-txt-tab-delimited-on-a-mac)

I also tried to do it for one file to see how it works but with no success

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd
import csv


def main():
    # I open the xlsx file 
    myfile = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
    # I don't know the name of sheet
    mysheet = myfile.sheet_by_index(0)
    # I open the output csv
    myCsvfile = open('my.csv', 'wb')
    # I write the file into it
    wr = csv.writer(myCsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for rownum in xrange(mysheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(mysheet.row_values(rownum))
    myCsvfile.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: apart from all wrong variable names, your program works fine.  what's your problem exactly? what's the error?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre can you modify my variable names in my question ? I am using Mac with python2.7

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre there is no error, it just does not create any file

Comment: Did you remember to run `main()`?

Comment: quickfix: `def main():
    # I open the xlsx file
    myfile = xlrd.open_workbook('Classeur1.xlsx')
    # I don't know the name of sheet
    mysheet = myfile.sheet_by_index(0)
    # I open the output csv
    myCsvfile = open('my.csv', 'wb')
    # I write the file into it
    wr = csv.writer(myCsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for rownum in xrange(mysheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(mysheet.row_values(rownum))
    myCsvfile.close()`

Comment: That wasn't the only change @nik ... `MyCsvfile` needs to be lowercase `myCsvfile`, and `sh` also does not exist at `sh.nrows`. And you never called `main()`, so right, no file gets opened or created.

Comment: @cricket_007 I corrected the syntax but still does not work. so I should remove the `def main():` ? can you give me a reason ? when I remove that I get this error myfile = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: All you did was define a function, it does not run unless you explicitly call it. Or you can remove it, but whitespace is very important in Python, so you have to fix the indentation.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know myself :-D it got messy once everybody gave me comment so I was confused. Now I changed it. but now it gives me this error IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real need for the main function.

And not sure about your indentation problems, but this is how I would write what you have. (And should work, according to first comment above)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd
import csv

# open the output csv
with open('my.csv', 'wb') as myCsvfile:
    # define a writer
    wr = csv.writer(myCsvfile, delimiter="\t")

    # open the xlsx file 
    myfile = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
    # get a sheet
    mysheet = myfile.sheet_by_index(0)

    # write the rows
    for rownum in xrange(mysheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(mysheet.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: I am getting this error  `wr.writerow(mysheet.row_values(rownum))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 131-132: ordinal not in range(128)`do you know why?

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer but I would appreciate if you could modify it to give me .txt instead .csv , if possible

Comment: Umm.. `open('my.txt', 'wb')`? File extensions are highly irrelevant to the problem

Comment: it converts to it `.txt`but still my other function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207261/how-to-make-a-pair-combination-per-each-line does not work on this txt , I think it is because I am converting it by Mac :-(((( I've been working on this forever and no solution yet :-(

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you. Open up your Python scripts in PyCharm or something, setup some breakpoints, then start debugging. I don't think the Mac is the problem - Python is cross-platform.

Comment: I have tried to debug it but no sucess. I am very sure that it is something to do with space in my input. I tried to do different line.split like  `elems = line.split('\r')`  or `elems = line.split('\n')`or `elems = line.split('\t')` .

Comment: OH MY GOD, I solved it , look at this , I only add rU to open file `open('data.txt','rU')` it works like a charm :-D :-D :-D  here i found info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785233/convert-r-text-to-n-so-readlines-works-as-intended

Comment: That mode is deprecated, so I'm sure it'll work for now. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: you can also look at this question if you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213905/string-manipulation-and-adding-values-based-on-row-they-are

Comment: Regarding your new question, I don't think `mysheet.row_values(rownum))` works the way you think it does. The gist you have contains quotes as if it quoted the entire line of the spreadsheet

Comment: what is then the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Why go with so much pain when you can do it in 3 lines:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')

file.to_csv('myfile.xlsx',
             sep="\t",
             index=False)
```